# why child component not showing console.log Outputs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

My child component showing its html Output fine but its showing console.log output in console and console.log working fine everywhere else in the project .And showing no error about this component in console

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

console.log('Mian is here')

@Component({
  selector: 'app-media-input',
  templateUrl: './media-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./media-input.component.scss']
})

export class MediaInputComponent implements OnInit {
  Gallery='hello'

  @Input('media') media
  constructor() { 
    console.log('okok', this.media);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('okomianas');
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `angularjs` tag??

Comment: what is Gallery ? post your parent html as well

Comment: this is what im using in parent component @Sajeetharan
    `<app-media-input [media]="resource"></app-media-input>`

Answer (score 0):

Usual syntax should be,

```
  @Input() media: yourType;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer yeah its working but its only showing console output of constructure one but not the one which is inside the ngOninit

Comment: you should log console.log(this.media);

Comment: Produce a plunker